# Why is my custom Windows service not doing its work?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

I have created a service which would show "Hello World" message when it starts..
The OnStart method of the service consists the following code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
}
```

The service is installed perfectly, but when I start the service I get the following error.

> The RucService on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the performance Logs and Alert service.

[image: Error Message]

So it does not show the message Hello World. Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a message box from a Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786598/show-a-message-box-from-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to use UI elements (Windows Forms) from a service. A service shouldn't have a UI component. If there needs to be a user interface for configuration, etc., have the service pull its settings from a database and create a separate application for managing the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Keep services & UI separate.  Bad practice to try & use Windows Froms from within a service.  If you need to integrate the two, you can try using sockets or some other IPC mechanism.