# Service running but no message box shown

Tags: c#, service, controller, task

I have a service and I'm starting this service from a form:

```
ctl = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => s.ServiceName == "ServiceA").First();
ctl.Start();
MessageBox.Show(ctl.Status.ToString());//Running
```

I checked the service in the Task Manager of windows 8 and it is running.
However I added a code like that :

```
public ServiceA()//constructor method
{
MessageBox.Show("Started");
}
```

But when the process is running, I can't see any message box which has its content like "Started". What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows services do not allow showing of message boxes.
You can refer to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786598/show-a-message-box-from-a-windows-service) for more details.