# how do i show my text as an error text in throw exception?

Tags: c#

i wrote a window service project, i want to display an error message when some error occur, in OnStart() function, (with throw) then service isn't started.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // do some code ...

    // when some error occur:
    throw new System.Exception("my error text!!!");
 }
```

it is ok, and service isn't started. But 'my error text' isn't displayed!!! and the system shows own error text("Some services stop automatically if ...")

how do i show my text as an error text for users, when he starts service and some error occur?

Comment: For a desktop application, you need to write dialog to display the message, the default WER dialog does not show the exception message to the user. For a Windows Service, it _can't/shouldn't_ display anything to the user.

Comment: really!!! it can't display any message to user.

Comment: See the answers in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786598/show-a-message-box-from-a-windows-service

Comment: Forget about it. Follow the right path as Joonas Koski mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to display an error message using the `MessageBox` function of the `User32.dll`:

```
private const int MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION = 0x00200000;
private const int MB_ICONERROR = 0x00000010;

[DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "MessageBox")]
private extern static int MsgBox(int hwnd, string lpText, string lpCaption, uint uType); 

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // do some code ...

    // when some error occurred:
    MsgBox(0, "my error text!!!", "Error", MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION | MB_ICONERROR);
    throw new ApplicationException();
}
```