# Validate app config value and throw error while starting windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need to validate a AppSettings value from app config while starting the windows service.

When user tries to start windows service from servics.msc, if the AppSettings
value is empty, I need to raise an error and prevent windows service from starting.

I understand I can write the error to event log but I would prefer to raise the error in services.msc console itself.

**Sample error message while starting the service**[image]

Comment: You mean on the error dialog box in services.msc?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Yes

Comment: Please check this answer from another post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2786697/4222487

Comment: You can't pass an error message from a service to services.msc.  The closest you can get is to specify an error code (a 32-bit number) but even then I'm not sure whether services.msc will display it.  Instead, provide the user with a custom application to use to start the service.  That way, you can convert the error code to a message.  (Although I'm not sure offhand how to set the service-specific error code from a .NET service.  If necessary, you could use IPC to pass the error message from the service to the application instead.)