# Need to call functions and subs from windows services in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and have a project that I have made my first windows service. Now I have a function that retrieves a count of transactions. I would like to call that function and put the results in a text file. I can hard code a stream to put into the text file, but whenever I call the function, the services just crashes. Not errors just dies. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried coding the function inside of the service-nope
I coded the function in a separate class-Nope! dies when I call it

```
Private Sub BrowserMailSender(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        FileIO.WriteToFile("service is started:" + Now + vbNewLine)
        My_Count() 'service dies here
        FileIO.WriteToFile("end" + vbNewLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
```

the function works if I call from the main project but I would like the service to run and save the data behind the scenes.

Comment: Are you sure the service is dying there? Or is `My_Count` throwing an exception, which transfers control to the `Catch` block, and then the process locks up on `MsgBox`? You can't use `MsgBox` in a Windows Service. Try logging the exception to a file.

Comment: I have removed the message box. same results. the only thing that my_count does is writes to a text file. that's it. I have not even put the function in that retrieves the data yet. Still it dies when I call My_count( which is a public shared sub)\

Comment: madreflection ! YOU DA MAN! That msgbox was the problem. When I took that out an used "ex.message" I started getting some understandable error discriptions! You are the BEST OF THE BEST! Thanks!

Comment: @madreflection Could you enter your answer so I could mark it and you will get the credit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `MsgBox` is at the root of the problem.  A Windows Service runs in a context where it does not have the ability to present a User Interface to the user.  You'll have to find another way to communicate errors, such as the Event Log or a log file.

Prior to Vista, the line between services and the user was permeable, partly because the OS wasn't yet designed to keep them isolated, and partly because most users ran with full administrative privileges all the time.  From Vista forward, you have to work "in the dark".

There *are* ways present a UI to the user, and one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2786598) briefly mentions one of them.  However, I would caution you against trying to present a UI at all.  The main principle of a service is that it sits in the background and does things without requiring the user to interact with it.  Presenting a UI for events that the user is not aware are happening at that moment is an asymmetrical relationship.  It could block your service indefinitely when a user isn't expecting to have to interact with it to allow it to continue.